# Use Reduce to modify certain words in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

```
keywords = ["fish", "blue"]
phrase = 'one fish two fish red fish blue fish'
actual = ???

assert_equal 'one FISH two FISH red FISH BLUE FISH', actual
```

In short, using reduce, what should I replace ??? with above.

In long, is there a way to use reduce to modify each word in a string for which a condition is met. In this case I want to `upcase` each `word` in `phrase` that is included in `keywords`. I would imagine I could use this method, with some modification, to delete every instance of a word or replace it. I know about `sub` and `gsub` but I'm doing a problem set that leads me to believe this is possible with reduce. I've been to the docs with no avail.

I am only interested in solutions using reduce, or an explanation why reduce does not work in this case.

I got it to work using.

```
actual = keywords.reduce('one fish two fish red fish blue fish'){|memo,word| memo.gsub(word,word.upcase) }
```

Garret's comment lead me in the right direction. I may have been unclear, initially I just didn't want a `gsub` solution outside of `reduce`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I see two data here: keywords and phrase. Phrase is not really a collection (but could be easily turned into one), and reduce is generally used on collections. Keywords, however is. So, it think the object you want to `reduce` might be `keywords`, and the initial value for reduce might be `phrase`... (and you may still end up using `gsub` or similar...)

Comment: You should state your question at the beginning, something like, "Given an array of words, keywords, and a string, I wish to return a string that is the same string with the words contained in keywords (case indifferent) capitalized." On re-reading, I see you are only interested in solutions that use the method `Hash#reduce`. That's fine, but you may be doing yourself a disservice by requiring that a particular approach or method be used. If you wish to edit your question, I suggest you avoid drawing attention to the fact that it's an edit. If necessary, explain why you've edited in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

If using reduce, I imagine you can start by splitting your string within whitespaces (if it is normalized to have always a separation by one whitespace), then check if the current word in the block is in the keywords array if so, push it to the memo its uppercased version plus a whitespace to the right, otherwise just the word (plus the whitespace):

```
new_phrase = phrase.split.reduce('') do |memo, word|
  pushed_word = if keywords.include?(word)
                  word.upcase
                else
                  word
                end
  memo << "#{pushed_word} "
end

p new_phrase
# "one FISH two FISH red FISH BLUE FISH "
```

As you'll finish with one additional right whitespace, you can use `rstrip` to get rid of it.

Comment: What if, alternatively, you reduced the keywords, and not the phrase?

Comment: How's that @Garrett? could you enlighten me?

Comment: There is an implicit assumption that the OP seems to make that the thing to be reduced is the phrase (and I think you picked up on that assumption). However, the phrase is not a collection, so it has to be made into one, ergo with split. _But_, what if that assumption is wrong, and the target object to call reduce on is actually `keywords`?

Comment: Who're you referring to @CarySwoveland?

Comment: I really appreciate the way you share your knowledge in all your answers @CarySwoveland, and in this way I respect you. But adding words for others is nothing but annoying. Did you see the _I am only interested in solutions using reduce, or an explanation why reduce does not work in this case._? this is an answer which uses `reduce`. Of course, if I answer anything else it wouldn't be what the user expects as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

```
f1 = def upcase_fish(str); str.gsub('fish', 'FISH'); end
f2 = def upcase_blue(str); str.gsub('blue', 'BLUE'); end
[f1, f2].reduce(phrase){ |str, f| Method.send f, str }
```

Explanantion

Calling several functions, such that the output of one function is the input of the next function, is a common use case. E.g. here we have two functions: one that capitalizes 'fish' and the other - 'blue'. Of course, we could have added other transformations as well, like removing trailing whitespace, capitalizing the first letter etc. In functional programming this can be achieved by reducing a collection of functions. We first initialize the result with the original `phrase` and then apply f1 followed by f2. This is equivalent to:
`f2(f1(phrase))`.

Comment: IMO this is needlessly clever and no more functional than the more idiomatic and easier to read solution OP came up with.

Comment: @JordanRunning agreed, I just wanted to show a more general idiom. For example, if other transformations besides capitalization are needed, my approach could be easily extended.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple ways of doing that. Both are intended to be relatively efficient and share the method [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) and the regular expression:

```
r = /\p{Alpha}+/
```

This matches one or more Unicode letters.

```
keywords = ["fish", "blue"]
phrase = "one fish two Fish red fisH blue fish."
```

Notice that in I've capitalized the first "Fish", upcased the "H" in the second "FisH" and added a period.

**Use the form of `String#gsub`that employs a hash for making substitutions**

```
subs = keywords.each_with_object({}) { |word,h|
  h[word] = word.capitalize }
  #=> {"fish"=>"Fish", "blue"=>"Blue"} 
subs.default_proc = Proc.new { |_,word|
  subs.include?(word.downcase) ? word.upcase : word } 
  #=> #<Proc:0x000059dc26dd1510@(irb):95> 
phrase.gsub(r, subs)
  #=> "one Fish two FISH red FISH Blue Fish."
```

The default proc returns a string if `word` is not a key of `subs`. If `word.downcase` is is a key of `subs`, `word.upcase` is returned; else `word` is returned unchanged. See [Hash#default_proc=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D).

**Use a set to speed lookups**

```
require 'set'

subs = keywords.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"fish", "blue"}> 
phrase.gsub(r) { |word|
  subs.include?(word.downcase) ? word.upcase : word }
  #=> "one FISH two FISH red FISH BLUE FISH."
```

Comment: It was only after I posted my answer did I see that answers were required to use the method `Hash#reduce`. I will let my answer stand as I would like to show ways to obtain the desired result which are not subject to that requirement.